# Sqlsrv_field_metadata with name and type

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sqlsrv

Working on converting my mysql php code to sqlsrv, but having issue how to grap the type and name with sqlsrv_field_metadata.

This is the code: EDIT ( I have pasted the whole code here)

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT tasks.title as Oppgaver, routines.value as Verdi, DATE_FORMAT(routines.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as Dato, routines.time as Tid, emps.user_name as Ansatt
    FROM routines, task_routine, tasks, emps
    WHERE routines.id = task_routine.routine_id
    AND task_routine.task_id = tasks.id
    AND (tasks.title  Like 'C_%') AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
    ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time";
  }



 $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . sqlsrv_error(). "<br>" . sqlsrv_errno()); 


$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

/*for ($i = 0; $i < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $type = sqlsrv_field_metadata($result,$i);
    echo sqlsrv_field_metadata($result,$i) . "\t";
    if ($type == "real")
    {
        $reals[] = $i;
    }
}*/

$metaData = sqlsrv_field_metadata($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $metaData; $i++) {
   $type = $metaData[$i]["Type"];
   echo $metaData[$i]["Name"] . "\t";
   if ($type === SQL_REAL) {
      $reals[] = $i;
   }
}


print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = sqlsrv_num_rows($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<sqlsrv_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";

}
```

MYSQL ( WHICH WORKS)

```
$sql = "
SELECT measurements.title as Maling, routines.value as Verdi, DATE_FORMAT(routines.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as Dato, routines.time as Tid, pools.name as Basseng, emps.user_name as Ansatt
FROM routines, measure_routine, measurements, pools, emps
WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
AND (measurements.title  Like 'T_%') AND measure_routine.pool_id=pools.id AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;

";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $type = mysql_field_type($result,$i);
    echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
    if ($type == "real")
    {
        $reals[] = $i;
    }
}



print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

I searched on the docoumentation but didn't found out how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296197.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you echo `sqlsrv_field_metadata($stmt)` as json object, you can see how to use that function.

Taken from [msdn sqlsrv_field_metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296197.aspx) :

```
$tsql = "SELECT ReviewerName, Comments FROM Production.ProductReview";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $tsql);

echo json_encode(sqlsrv_field_metadata($stmt));
```

will result a JSON string something like:

```
// Just example, related with nothing
[{
  "Name":"Id",
  "Type":-5,
  "Size":null,
  "Precision":19,
  "Scale":null,
  "Nullable":0
},
{
  "Name":"Username",
  "Type":-9,"Size":50,
  "Precision":null,
  "Scale":null,
  "Nullable":0
}]
```

From MSDN again:

- `Name` : Name of the column to which the field corresponds.
- `Type` : Numeric value that corresponds to a SQL type.
- `Size` : Number of characters for fields of character type (char(n), varchar(n), nchar(n), nvarchar(n), XML). Number of bytes for fields of binary type (binary(n), varbinary(n), UDT). **NULL** for other SQL Server data types.
- `Precision` : The precision for types of variable precision (real, numeric, decimal, datetime2, datetimeoffset, and time). **NULL** for other SQL Server data types.
- `Scale` : The scale for types of variable scale (numeric, decimal, datetime2, datetimeoffset, and time). **NULL** for other SQL Server data types.
- `Nullable` : An enumerated value indicating whether the column is nullable (**SQLSRV_NULLABLE_YES**), the column is not nullable (**SQLSRV_NULLABLE_NO**), or it is not known if the column is nullable (**SQLSRV_NULLABLE_UNKNOWN**).

Looking again to the result:

- First row is a column with name `Id` (`"Name": "Id"`) with type `bigint` (**SQL_BIGINT (-5)**) and cannot be **NULL** (`Nullable`: 0)
- Second row is a columnd with name `Username` with type `nvarchar(50)` (`"Type": -9` and `"Size": 50`) and cannot be **NULL**

So, how to get name and types?

Define an array and give it value of `sqlsrv_field_metadata($stmt)`:

```
$metaData = sqlsrv_field_metadata($stmt); // $result instead of $stmt in your case
```

Now you can loop with this array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $metaData; $i++) {
   $type = $metaData[$i]["Type"];
   echo $metaData[$i]["Name"] . "\t";
   if ($type === SQL_REAL) {
      $reals[] = $i;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm! I changed it but it ended up with excel crashing when I try to open the file. Maybe the files becomes to large or something ? I will put the whole code in the edit. Thanks.

Comment: I can't add much more about excel, first of all, does my answer work (I mean can you get results as you expected)? And second, about excel, is the excel file created successfully and later when you try to open it, does it crash? One more thing to add, I suggest you to use `PHPExcel` which is a good library about creating excel files and is easy to use.